# Simple TCP server with Akka.NET

Tags: c#, akka.net, akka.net-streams, akka.net-networking

Hi I'm learning to use Akka.net and what I want to do is, create a simple TCP server that will periodically send data to the tcp connection. (which will then be picked up by a processingjs client and display in the output)

Not sure what I'm missing here. Could any of you experts shed some light on the issue?

These are my actors:

```
using Akka.Actor;
using Akka.IO;
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ActorTcpProcessing
{
    public class ProcessingServer : ReceiveActor
    {  
        public ProcessingServer()
        { 
            Receive<Tcp.Bound>(TcpBoundHandler);
            Receive<Tcp.Connected>(TcpConnectedHandler);
        }

        internal static Props Create()
        {
            return Props.Create(() => new ProcessingServer());
        }

        private void TcpBoundHandler(Tcp.Bound bound)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Listening on {0}", bound.LocalAddress);
        }
         
        private void TcpConnectedHandler(Tcp.Connected connected)
        { 
            var tcpConnection = Sender; 

            var connectionHandler = Context.ActorOf(SensorReader.CreateReader(tcpConnection));
           
            tcpConnection.Tell(new Tcp.Register(connectionHandler));
        }
    }

    internal class SensorReader : ReceiveActor
    {
        private readonly IActorRef _tcpConnection;

        public SensorReader(IActorRef tcpConnection)
        {
            _tcpConnection = tcpConnection;

            Receive<SensorDataReceived>(TcpWriteSensorData);
        }

        internal static Props CreateReader(IActorRef connectionHandler)
        {
            return Props.Create(() => new SensorReader(connectionHandler));
        }

        private void TcpWriteSensorData(SensorDataReceived receivedData)
        {
            _tcpConnection.Tell(Tcp.Write.Create(ByteString.FromString(receivedData.SensorData + "\n")));
        }
    }
}
```

I am under the impression that when I register the `SensorReader` on a `Tcp.Connected` message, all I need to do is send a `SensorData` message to the stream.
as such: `_sys.EventStream.Publish(new SensorData("sensor-data[x]"));`

However, this doesn't seem to work.
I get the following log message:

```
[INFO][11/09/2021 10:22:05 AM][Thread 0004][akka://tcp-processing/deadLetters] Message [Bound] from [akka://tcp-processing/system/IO-TCP/$a#1070400244] to [akka://tcp-processing/deadLetters] was not delivered. [1] dead letters encountered. If this is not an expected behavior then [akka://tcp-processing/deadLetters] may have terminated unexpectedly. This logging can be turned off or adjusted with configuration settings 'akka.log-dead-letters' and 'akka.log-dead-letters-during-shutdown'.
```

This is how I'm sending the Tcp.Bind message to my server.

```
using System;
using Akka.IO;
using Akka.Actor;
using System.Net;
using Topshelf;

namespace ActorTcpProcessing
{
    class StreamTcpService : ServiceControl
    {
        ActorSystem _sys;

        public bool Start(HostControl hostControl)
        {
            _sys = ActorSystem.Create("tcp-processing");
            var server = _sys.ActorOf(ProcessingServer.Create(), nameof(ProcessingServer));
            var tcpManager = _sys.Tcp();

            
            tcpManager.Tell(new Tcp.Bind(
                server, 
                new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 10002)));

            _sys.EventStream.Publish(new SensorData("sensor-data[x]"));

            return true;
        }

        public bool Stop(HostControl hostControl)
        {
            _sys.Terminate().ContinueWith(task =>
            {
                if (task.IsCompleted && !task.IsCanceled)
                    Console.WriteLine("Stream Tcp stopped");
            });

            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, I am specifying the `server` as the handler of the Bound message. Or am I completely wrong?

Also, I must mention that when I start my processingjs client, I do receive a `Tcp.Connected` message to my `ProcessingServer`, which in turn creates the `SensorReader` and registers as the handler.

I'd also like to know am I using the `EventStream` publish correctly?

```
_sys.EventStream.Publish(new SensorData("sensor-data[x]"));
```

Any help to get this is highly appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is at line:

```
tcpManager.Tell(new Tcp.Bind(server,new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 10002)));
```

This is a bit misleading, but `server` in the constructor of `Tcp.Bind` is the handler of all incoming connections in the form of `Tcp.Connected`, not the actor that will receive the `Tcp.Bound` message.

The `Tcp` actor will reply with `Tcp.Bound` to the `Sender` of the `Tcp.Bind` message. To fix your problem, you should pass the `IActorRef` reference of the Actor expected to receive the `Tcp.Bound` message instead of the original sender. In your case:

```
tcpManager.Tell(new Tcp.Bind(server, new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 10002)), server);
```

Comment: Oh. amazing. thank you for the detailed explanation.